# CSS align dropdown with it parent in navigation

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a floating navigation over header but i cant align the dropdowns to the middle of it parent. This is what i made till now:

```
#menu .dropdown {

    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}

.dropdown-content {

    display: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    /*margin-left: -30px;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;

}

.dropdown-content a {

    color: black !important; 
    background: white !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

}
```

https://codepen.io/titan_s/pen/ZJdwKw

I was looking for some solutions but i didnt find anything what could help me solve my problem. Any advices with the good will be appreciated as well.

Comment: The dropdowns look center aligned in relation to their parents. Tested in both Chrome and Safari. Could you please clarify?

Comment: They look center aligned to me as well.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what you're looking for?

Comment: They look so but i dont want them to be so wide, i want them be as wide as the text in them + padding